# Name of a array inside a mixed array in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following php array:

```
Array ( [0] => fdsa.txt 
        [1] => lubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64.iso
        [2] => Solicitacao_de_Liberacao_a_Rede_WIFI.xlsx
        [teste\] => Array ( [0] => pasta1.txt [1] => pasta2.txt ) 
        [teste2\] => Array ( [0] => pasta3.txt [1] => pasta4.txt ) )
```

I want to use `foreach` to run through the array and echo everything

```
foreach($map as $arquivo){
    echo $arquivo."<br/>";  
}
```

But i want to show the name of the arrays instead of what is inside them like this:

```
fdsa.txt 
lubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64.iso
Solicitacao_de_Liberacao_a_Rede_WIFI.xlsx
teste\
teste2\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `is_array` to test if it's an array --  If it is .. Then display the `key` rather than the `value` ..  IE

```
foreach($map as $key => $arquivo){
    if ( is_array($arquivo) ){
        echo "$key <br/>";
    }else{
        echo "$arquivo <br/>";
    }  
}
```

Side note -- There is no need to concatenate your `echo` statement if you are using a single variable and double quotes.  Just makes for cleaner code.